# I installed superset version 1.01 recently and I'm not able to see the parameter button on the SQL Lab page. I log in under the admin role

Tags: jinja2, apache-superset

I'm using postgres database and logging in as admin. watching YouTube videos and other online documentation I can see that other users have this button enabled but for some reason it doesn't appear in my installation. I'm thinking that it must be something in the config.py file. Everything is fairly vanilla I haven't changed any parameters at this point.

Answer (score -1):

From [answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47541224/allowing-users-to-only-view-data-related-to-them-in-apache-superset) you need to set this flag in **superset_config.py**

```
FEATURE_FLAGS = {
    "ENABLE_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING": True,
}
```