# how to get logined user name in apache superset using sql lab?

Tags: python, apache-superset

i need to get logged user in Apache superset `sqllab`. i tried with query

```
SELECT  '{{ current_username()) }}'
```

but it not returning logged username. documentation shows add  `JINJA_CONTEXT_ADDONS` in your superset configuration `(superset_config.py)`.
where i can add `superset_config.py` and how to add `jinja_context_add_on`.

Answer (score 2):

I have answered a similar question here -

[Allowing users to only view data related to them in Apache Superset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47541224/allowing-users-to-only-view-data-related-to-them-in-apache-superset/67145679#67145679)

To Summarise -

In superset_config.py add the following -

```
FEATURE_FLAGS = {
    "ENABLE_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING": True,
}
```

superset_config.py is a configuration file to override the default behavior of Apache Superset. Just make sure that the file is in PYTHONPATH.

More details here -
https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/configuring-superset

Answer (score 1):

When Superset is deployed to k8s it needs to modify Helm config to enable *templating*: (see https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/running-on-kubernetes):

```yaml
# See settings https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/configuring-superset
configOverrides:
  my_override: |
    FEATURE_FLAGS = {
        "ENABLE_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING": True
    }
```